# Can you implement a condor options trading strategy in a spreadsheet?

Tags: options

Can you implement a condor options trading strategy in a spreadsheet?

Could you give an example?

Comment: Too vague, more details are needed to answer this. Moreover am I wrong if I say that the answer you want should include an XL-spreadsheet implementation of a condor strategy ?

Comment: Don't understand the question "implement a trading strategy in a spreadsheet" - voting to close.

Comment: I'm sure you can, but I doubt someone will do it for you.  [This search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=iron+condor+filetype%3Axls) may be helpful.